# Why same Electron app that works perfectly in Linux crashes in Windows 10 (after a reload)?

Tags: javascript, electron

On a 64-bit Windows machine, I'm running an Electron app that uploads a file and logs its first line in the browser's console. Everything works fine until I reload the app. Once reloaded, every subsequent file uploads do not log any line. However, I can see the file is uploaded in the console log as shown in the screenshot below,

**Electron version**
10.1.2

**Windows version**
Windows 10 Enterprise (1909)

**To Reproduce**

1. Run the electron fiddle gist from the link below
   https://gist.github.com/wasimaftab/6bd20e0ec4540ddc855d2744115bdb42
2. click Upload File button and upload any text file
   In the browser's console and you should see first line of the uploaded file
   as highlighted using red rectangle in the following screenshot,

[image]

3. Now reload the app by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + R
4. click Upload File button and upload any text file
5. you will NOT see the first line of the uploaded file as depicted in the following screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is FIXED in electron v10.1.5